# Помогите скрыть элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counts = $('#grid li a').size();
  $('.col-lg-9 p').text('at the moment their ' + counts);
});

$('.col-lg-3 p').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this).attr('data-id');
  a = a.substr(1);
  $('#grid li a').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass(a) && a != 'all')
      $(this).addClass('hide');
    else
      $(this).removeClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <h1>Hello, my works below</h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <p data-id="#optam" class="pull-right"><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">optam</button></p>
      <p data-id="#math" class="pull-right"><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">math</button></p>
      <p data-id="#all" class="pull-right"><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">all</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt">
      <ul class="grid effect-2" id="grid">
        <li>
          <a class="optam" href="proj/p5.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/cpp5.jpg"></a>
          <h2>Practical 5</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="math" href="proj/p5.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/cpp5.jpg"></a>
          <h2>Practical 5</h2>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Когда я нажимаю в классе `col-lg-3` кнопку <kbd>math</kbd> или <kbd>optam</kbd>, то пикча не подходящая под фильтр пропадает, но `<h2>Practical 5</h2>` остается. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

К коду, конечно, очень много вопросов - начиная, от использования устаревшего jQuery API (метод size(), например) до не совсем верного кода (например, в e.preventDefault() нет необходимости, когда в данном случае обрабатываешь событие click на элементе p: какое у параграфа поведение по умолчанию для того, чтобы его превентить?)

Но, если отвечать на вопрос, то элемент

```
<h2>Practical 5</h2>
```

не исчезает, потому что он находится не в `<a>` элементе, а ты здесь присваиваешь класс a элементу (линке)

```
$('#grid li a').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass(a) && a != 'all')
        $(this).addClass('hide');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('hide');
});
```

Вот изображение исчезает, потому что находится в `<a>` элементе

```
<li><a class="optam" href="proj/p5.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/cpp5.jpg"></a><h2>Practical 5</h2></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**:

```
$('#grid li a').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass(a) && a != 'all') {
      $(this).addClass('hide').closest("li").find("h2").addClass('hide');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('hide').closest("li").find("h2").removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

**Вариант 2**:  используем [element + next](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_previous_next.asp)

> при помощи element + next получаем следующий элемент

```
if(a != 'all')
{
  $('#grid li a, #grid li a + h2').addClass("hide");
  $('#grid li a[class*="'+a+'"], #grid li a[class*="'+a+'"] + h2').removeClass("hide");
}
else{
  $('#grid li a, #grid li a + h2').removeClass("hide");
}
```

**Вариант 3**:  используем [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> при помощи siblings() получаем **всех** братьев и сестер в наборе DOM (в родителе).

**!** Если У Вас будут сторонние строки в `<li>` к которым не должен применяться класс `.hide`, данное решение не подойдет

```
if(a != 'all')
{
  $('#grid li a').addClass("hide").siblings().addClass("hide");
  $('#grid li a[class*="'+a+'"').removeClass("hide").siblings().removeClass("hide");
}
else{
  $('#grid li a').removeClass("hide").siblings().removeClass("hide");
}
```